# How many layers should I stack in a sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, sequential

I am trying to train a sequential model using the LSTM layer.

The size of sequence data for learning is as follows:

```
x = np.array(sequences)
y = to_categorical(labels).astype(int)

x.shape => (1800, 34, 48)
y.shape => (1800, 20)
```

After that, I make a sequential model and try to stack the LSTM layer and the dense layer, but I don't know how much to do that.

First, I did something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:3]))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```

However, this doesn't seem to fit my case as I followed someone else's code.

How many layers should I stack in a sequential model?

Comment: Depends friendo, you see layers are nothing but extra biases and weights if you add more, naturally it will become heavier but it is expected to increase the accuracy. So if you just want speed, just cut it short and diminish the amount of layers.

Comment: Usually there isn't a formula or rule to determine the number of LSTM layers to use. You always have a starting point, such as a model that was successful in a given paper or article and you move from there. The most important thing is to experiment. Try out using less layers or more even. A good starting point is essential, so have a look at similar problems to yours and see what worked. And then experiment as much as you want until you notice a decreasing effect on performance from your changes, this usually means you are near the optimum parameters for your given problem.

Comment: Note that the more layers you have, the more parameters, therefore the more prone your model is to overfitting. It's all about balance at the end of the day